# How can I trigger actions between siblings in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
       <Sibling1/>
       <Sibling2/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Let's say the user touches `sibling1` and I want `sibling2` to turn green as a result. [This tutorial](https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17) explains how I can pass information between siblings, **but not how I can prompt the receiving component to realize that the change occurred**:

> Not surprisingly, to pass data between siblings, you have to use the parent as an intermediary. First pass the data from the child to the parent, as an argument into a callback from the parent. Set this incoming parameter as a state on the parent component, then pass it as a prop to the other child (see above example). The sibling can then use the data as a prop.

I'm deeply confused about why React Native wouldn't make such a thing intuitive and easy since it's an extremely common need in any application and completely trivial to do on the browser with a basic library like JQuery.

How can I *trigger actions* between siblings in React Native?

Comment: Forgive me if this is actually trivial but I'm new to react. So far, I can't see how it would be trivial.

Comment: The flow of data in react is parent <-> child. So if you need to communicate between siblings and trigger actions, you need to go through the parent. Another option would be Redux or the ContextAPI. It's all about state management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `componentWillReceiveProps` lifeCycle to get a notification of when the component receives an update on one or more of its props.

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
       <Sibling1 onClick={() => this.setState({ color: '#00ff00')}/>
       <Sibling2 color={this.state.color} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}


export default class Sibling2 extends Component {
      componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(nextProps.color != this.state.color) {
         // here you know the changed ocurred
          this.setState({ color: nextProps.color });
        }
      }
      render() {
        return (this.state.color);
      }
    }
```

Comment: When running `setState` from `Sibling1`, `Sibling2` will never know anything about it. `state` is private and not shared between components.

Comment: the `setState` will trigger `Parent`, it is the `Parent` state that will be update, which will cause a re-render and therefore render `Sibling2` with the new prop. This code does nothing with `Sibling1` state

Comment: `setState` will not trigger `Parent` though. You need to pass a Function prop from `Parent` to `Sibling`, and this Function has to be in charge of changing the `Parent`'s `state`.

Comment: that is being done, there is an arrow function being passed down to `Sibiling1`, arrow functions is just a short way of what you are saying.